# how to point to the next node in linked list and print the value

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was trying to store values in linked list in c++ and printing them. But I don't know whether I am writing the proper code or not. When I create a new node-insert value-print this works but. But when i use temp at the last to print all the values is not working

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int val;
    node *next;
};
int main()
{
    node *temp = new node();    //creating the first node
    node *head, *tail;
    temp->val= 1;               //assigning value to the first node
    head = temp;                //head contains the address of 1st node

    cout<< "head value" <<head << endl;
    cout << "head value" << temp << endl;
    cout<< "1st value" << temp->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;


    //============================================second node
    temp = temp->next;
    temp = new node();
    temp->val = 2;

    cout << "head value" << head << endl;
    cout << "head value" << temp << endl;
    cout << "2rd value" << temp->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;


    //============================================third node
    temp = temp->next;
    temp = new node();
    temp->val = 3;

    cout << "head value" << head << endl;
    cout << "head value" << temp << endl;
    cout << "3rd value" << temp->val << endl;


    tail = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
    cout<< "=================================================" << endl;
    cout<< "value in head" << head->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;
    cout<< "the value temp is reset to head which is the location of first node" << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;

    //temp = NULL;
    temp = head;                          //add of first node is stored in temp
    cout<< "the value of head  " << head << endl;
    cout<< "the value of temp  " << temp << endl;


    //Problem from this ............................................................

    //temp->next = head->next;            

    cout << "the value of head  " << head->next << endl;
    cout << "the value of temp  " << temp->next << endl;

    cout<< "value in head + 1  " << temp->val << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

the  output shown where the address of *`temp->next`* not working
[output photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPX8j.png)

Comment: Although the answers are correct, your first step should be to step through your code in a debugger. Look at the addresses of things. Look at the contents of the node previously known as `temp` before and after changing `temp`. Asking the question is all very well, but you _must_ learn how to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp` is a separate variable that is it occupies a separate memory extent.

So after these statements

```
temp = temp->next;
temp = new node();
```

there is changed the variable `temp`. But the data member `temp->next` of the previously pointed node was not changed because `temp->next` occupies a different memory extent.

As result you does not have a linked list. You have separate nodes that are not linked.

You can achieve what you want the following way using the variable `temp` of the type `node **`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int val;
    node *next;
};

int main()
{
    node *head, *tail;
    node **temp = &head;
    *temp = new node();    //creating the first node
    ( *temp )->val= 1;    //assigning value to the first node

    cout<< "head value" <<head << endl;
    cout << "head value" << *temp << endl;
    cout<< "1st value" << ( *temp )->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;


    //============================================second node
    temp = &( *temp )->next;
    *temp = new node();
    ( *temp )->val = 2;

    cout << "head value" << head << endl;
    cout << "head value" << *temp << endl;
    cout << "2rd value" << ( *temp )->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;


    //============================================third node
    temp = &( *temp )->next;
    *temp = new node();
    ( *temp )->val = 3;

    cout << "head value" << head << endl;
    cout << "head value" << *temp << endl;
    cout << "3rd value" << ( *temp )->val << endl;


    tail = *temp;
    ( *temp )->next = NULL;
    cout<< "=================================================" << endl;
    cout<< "value in head" << head->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;
    cout<< "the value temp is reset to head which is the location of first node" << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;

    //temp = NULL;
    temp = &head;                          //add of first node is stored in temp
    cout<< "the value of head  " << head << endl;
    cout<< "the value of temp  " << *temp << endl;


    //Problem from this ............................................................

    //temp->next = head->next;            

    cout << "the value of head  " << head->next << endl;
    cout << "the value of temp  " << ( *temp )->next << endl;

    cout<< "value in head + 1  " << ( *temp )->next->val << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
head value0x55ab880e8c20
head value0x55ab880e8c20
1st value1
=================================================
head value0x55ab880e8c20
head value0x55ab880e9c50
2rd value2
=================================================
head value0x55ab880e8c20
head value0x55ab880e9c70
3rd value3
=================================================
value in head1
=================================================
the value temp is reset to head which is the location of first node
=================================================
the value of head  0x55ab880e8c20
the value of temp  0x55ab880e8c20
the value of head  0x55ab880e9c50
the value of temp  0x55ab880e9c50
value in head + 1  2
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
temp = temp->next;
```

makes `temp` point to the same memory as `temp->next` is pointing to. Which is a null pointer.

Then

```
temp = new node();
```

overwrites the previous value of `temp`, and makes it point to a newly allocated `node` structure.

The above two statements do no link a new node into the list.

Instead try something like

```
// At this point `temp` is pointing to the last node in the list
// Create a new node and link it into the list
temp->next = new node;  // Allocate a new `node` and link it into the list
temp = temp->next;  // Make `temp` point to the new node
temp->val = ...;  // Set the new value

...
```

Comment: You are mistaken. temp->next is initialized by zero.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow : Why?  I thought `new Pod;` left the object uninitialized.

Comment: @MartinBonner But there is new Pod();

Comment: @VladfromMoscow : and that is different?  Oh.  I didn't realize that.

Comment: @MartinBonner It's [*value initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), which is different from [*default initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

Comment: Yes, I understand the difference between value and default initialization - I just didn't realize you could trigger it like that.  (No wonder people in my office don't like C++ because it's so complex.)

Answer (score 0):

This worked..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int val;
    node *next;
};
int main()
{
    node *temp, *head, *tail;
    temp = new node();                  //creation of first node structure
    temp->val = 1;                      //value of 1st node
    head = temp;                        //assigning the temp address to head
    cout<< "the add of head  "<<head << endl;
    cout<< "the add of temp  "<< temp << endl;
    cout<< "the value in 1st node is  "<< temp->val << endl;
    cout<< "=================================================" << endl;

    temp->next = new node();            //creation of second node structure
    temp = temp->next;                  //over writing the first address of temp with the  
                                        //address of second node
    temp->val = 2;
    cout << "the add of head  " << head << endl;
    cout << "the add of temp  " << temp << endl;
    cout << "the value in 2nd node is  " << temp->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;

    temp->next = new node();            //creation of third node structure
    temp = temp->next;                  //over writing the second address of temp with the  
                                        //address of third node
    temp->val = 3;
    cout << "the add of head  " << head << endl;
    cout << "the add of temp  " << temp << endl;
    cout << "the value in 3nd node is  " << temp->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;

    temp->next = NULL;                  //the last node pointer pointers to null 

    temp = head;                        //temp is assigned the value of head which is
                                        //the address of 1st node
    cout << "the add of head  " << head << endl;
    cout << "the add of temp  " << temp << endl;
    cout << "the value in 1st node is  " << temp->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;

    temp = temp->next;                  //the address of second node is assigned to temp

    cout << "the add of head  " << head << endl;
    cout << "the add of temp  " << temp << endl;
    cout << "the value in 2nd node is  " << temp->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;

    temp = temp->next;                  //the address of third node is assigned to temp

    cout << "the add of head  " << head << endl;
    cout << "the add of temp  " << temp << endl;
    cout << "the value in 3nd node is  " << temp->val << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```